# spring java legacy code conflict java

Tags: java, spring

I am rather new to spring. I have a project that imports resources from 2 different components. The first component contains reference to legacy code and the second project is a new implementation. When running the application the projects conflict. The structure is something like this ..

```
Project 1 (instance)
Spring.xml ->imports resources from `Project 2`
e.g.    <import resource="classpath:Project2.xml" />
Pom.xml 

Project 2 
Spring.xml ->imports resource from `Project 3` 
e.g.    <import resource="classpath:Project3.xml" />
Pom.xml -> contains legacy code

Project 3
Spring.xml -> contains bean instantiation
    <import resource="classpath:ResourceX.xml" /> (resourceX is also refered to as a dependancy (legacy) in project 2.)
Pom.xml -> refers to new jar files
```

When  i run my code, how can i explicitly define that the import in `Project 3`, only referes to the dependancies in Project3. It seems that `Project 3 spring.xml` is trying to instantiate the beans using the legacy code from `Project 2` which it is failing.

Comment: If you need to refer only Project 3 then you should not import other jars into it.. Please explain the question much clear.

Comment: You have the main project that contains dependancies to legacy code. When i import project 3 , it looks on the class path and it finds the legacy code and passes incorrect values. Even THOUGH in project 3 i have its own dependancies. Is there a way to define the jar when importing a resource?